# Slicing a python string with intervals?

Tags: python, arrays, string

i have a string a="2:1,3:2,4:5,7:5"
i basically want to split this and assign 2,3,4,7 into an integer list and 1,2,5,5 into an other.I tried to us b=a.split(":") first and then c=b.split(",").I just get 21,32 etc.

So can you suggest a way to do this i'm way in over my head.

Comment: You can't have tried what you suggest. `b=a.split(":")` will return the list `['2', '1,3', '2,4', '5,7', '5']`. Then `c=b.split(",")` will raise an `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'`. So please show us your actual code.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that i used b="".join((a.split(":"))

Comment: Well, that's exactly where the problem was. If you `split` on `":"` and then `join` the result, that's just a complicated way to remove all of the `:` characters…

Comment: … although if every number is guaranteed to be a single digit, you _could_ actually just `zip(*c)`, because strings are sequences, just like lists and tuples, so `zip(*['21', '32', '45', '75'])` is `[('2', '3', '4', '7'), ('1', '2', '5', ''5)]`. (Then you still need the last step, to call `int` on each element in each tuple, and turn them into lists.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how you could possibly get `21` out of anything even remotely like what you say you used.

But you're on the right track. Let's go through step by step.

```
>>> a="2:1,3:2,4:5,7:5"
>>> b=a.split(":")
>>> b
['2', '1,3', '2,4', '5,7', '5']
```

OK, that isn't right, because you wanted to get `2` and `1` first, then `3` and `2`, and so on.

```
>>> b=a.split(',')
>>> b
['2:1', '3:2', '4:5', '7:5']
```

OK, now we want to `split` each thing in that `list`. How do we do that? You could write a `for` loop, or use `map`, but a list comprehension is probably the simplest:

```
>>> c=[element.split(':') for element in b]
[['2', '1'], ['3', '2'], ['4', '5'], ['7', '5']]
```

Now you've got your two lists, but they're zipped together. How do you unzip them? By zipping!

```
>>> d, e = zip(*c)
>>> d
('2', '3', '4', '7')
>>> e
('1', '2', '5', '5')
```

Now, you're almost there, but you want these to be lists of integers, rather than tuples of strings. List comprehensions again to the rescue:

```
>>> f = [int(element) for element in d]
>>> g = [int(element) for element in e]
>>> f
[2, 3, 4, 7]
>>> g
[1, 2, 5, 5]
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that i used b="".join((a.split(":")) .but thank you i am new to this and im forced to use python so i knew about zip.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [8]: a = "2:1,3:2,4:5,7:5"

In [9]: b, c = zip(*[map(int, t.split(':')) for t in a.split(',')])

In [10]: b
Out[10]: (2, 3, 4, 7)

In [11]: c
Out[11]: (1, 2, 5, 5)
```

Here, `b` and `c` are tuples. If required, turn them into lists by calling [`list()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list).

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that i used b="".join((a.split(":")) .but thank you i am new to this and im forced to use python so i knew about zip.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
>>> a = "2:1,3:2,4:5,7:5"
>>> l1, l2 = zip(*(map(int, p.split(':')) for p in a.split(',')))
>>> l1
(2, 3, 4, 7)
>>> l2
(1, 2, 5, 5)
```

`a.split(',')` is pretty self-explanatory. `map(int, p.split(':')) for p in a.split(',')` splits each of those resulting pairs of numbers and then converts them into integers.

`zip(*(...))` takes that generator and puts the first element of each pair into one list and the second into another list.

`l1, l2 = ...` is tuple unpacking. It's basically shorthand for `l1 = ...[0]` and `l2 = ...[1]`.

---

Another way would be:

```
>>> l = map(int, a.replace(',', ':').split(':'))
>>> l
[2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 7, 5]
>>> l1, l2 = l[::2], l[1::2]
```

This converts the commas into colons and then you can split it up with just `.split()`. `l[::2]` returns every even element and `l[1::2]` returns every odd element.

Comment: Collective intelligence at work! Thirteen seconds apart :)

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that i used b="".join((a.split(":")) .but thank you i am new to this and im forced to use python so i knew about zip.Thank you.